# Не срабатывающая команда $APPLICATION->ShowPanel

Tags: php, html, css, битрикс, админка

Не срабатывает команда `$APPLICATION->ShowPanel` (шаблон сайта взят с [W3layouts](https://w3layouts.com/template/publication-a-corporate-blogging-category-website-template/))
Привожу код файла

```php
<?php if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true) die(); ?>

<?php
use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset;
?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <!--<meta charset="utf-8">-->
    <?php
    $APPLICATION->ShowHead();
    ?>
    <title><?php $APPLICATION->ShowTitle(); ?></title>
    <?php
    Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/assets/css/style-starter.css');
    Asset::getInstance()->addString('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">');
    Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/owl/owlcarousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css');
    Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/owl/owlcarousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css');
    Asset::getInstance()->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/assets/jq/jquery-3.6.0.min.js');
    Asset::getInstance()->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/owl/owlcarousel/dist/owl.carousel.js');
    ?>

</head>

<body>

<div id="panel"><?php $APPLICATION->ShowPanel(); ?></div>

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu", "menu", array(
    "ALLOW_MULTI_SELECT" => "N",
        "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "left",
        "DELAY" => "N",
        "MAX_LEVEL" => "1",
        "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => array(
            0 => "",
        ),
        "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
        "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
        "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "main",
        "USE_EXT" => "N"
    ),
    false,
    array(
    "ACTIVE_COMPONENT" => "Y"
    )
);?>
```

В результате на экране выводится

[image: Шаблон без админ хэдера]

В чем причина?

Comment: Открой html-код страницы, посмотри что отрендерилось внутри `div id=panel`. Проверь, что под текущим пользователем имеет смысл выводить панель, т.е пользователь имеет право на какие-то кнопки в этой панели.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php $APPLICATION->ShowPanel(); ?>` - выводит панель Битрикса. Она выводится, если у пользователя есть разрешение хотя бы на одну из доступных кнопок на этой панели, если таких кнопок нет, то и панели не будет. Также, в настройках главного модуля, есть настройка "Панель инструментов публичного раздела", где можно явно указать кому всегда показывать такую панель, а кому никогда не показывать.

Проверьте доступные разрешения для пользователей, у которых нет этой панели, настройку в главном модуле.

**И еще как вариант**. Если панель Битрикса "свернута", она занимает достаточно мало места по высоте и таким образом, розовая полоса шаблона сайта стилями верстки может находится выше панели Битрикса, скрывая ее.